# SQL syntax error in updating a database value

Tags: sql, database, delphi

I'm update the money for one person only in a database. The money is saved as a currency and the email as a string. My SQL is throwing a syntax error

```
ADOQuery.sql.text:= ' UPDATE TblPlayerdetails SET Money = "' + Inttostr(NewAmount) + '" WHERE Email = "' + Playersemail + '"';
```

`Newamount` is an integer and `email` is a string.

Comment: Learn to use parameters and parameter placeholders!  Don't munge query strings with parameter values!

Comment: I dont understand what you mean could you elaborate

Comment: If you follow @GordonLinoff's advice, you are far less likely to get syntax errors like the one you have.  See e.g. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries.  Your existing SQL does not need the double-quotes around the Inttostr(NewAmount).

Comment: Could you rewrite the SQL for me or give an eg. I dont understand what you're trying to explain @MartynA

Comment: You should do it yourself, otherwise you will  learn nothing.  If you take the trouble to read that article, it fully explains parameterised queries.  This article which it links to shows how to specify the parameter values at run-time: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Supplying_Parameters_at_Runtime

Comment: I read the article and I tried it and its giving my an error.(Parameter object is improperly defined)

Comment: I am not going to try to guess what the error in your SQL might be.  I suggest you delete this q and ask a new one, incuding a mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: "My SQL is giving me a syntax error" Whenever you're reporting any sort of error code or message, **always always always** tell us what that *exact* error was.

Comment: If you did a basic search of this site for something like `[delphi] sql update syntax error`, or even `[delphi] sql syntax error`, you'd find dozens and dozens of existing posts. Almost every one of the answers to those questions stress **Stop concatenating your SQL, and use parameters instead** and include examples of doing so. Using parameters means you don't have to convert data types (you can use `.AsString` or `AsFloat` or `.AsDateTime`), you don't have to figure out what you need to quote and exactly how, and you're not vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping you would manage to work out what to do from the documentation I linked in comments, but on reflection I thought I had better provide a correct answer.

Set up the following code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AdoQuery2.SQL.Text := 'update moneytable set money = :money where id = :id';

  AdoQuery2.Parameters.ParamByName('ID').Value := 1;
  AdoQuery2.Parameters.ParamByName('Money').Value := 99;

  AdoQuery2.ExecSQL;
end;
```

The line

```
  AdoQuery2.SQL.Text := 'update moneytable set money = :money where id = :id';
```

sets up a parameterised  UPDATE statement.  The `:id` and `:money` are placeholders  for *parameter* values which will be provided separately.  The parameter names are ID and Money, though they could be given other names.  Note that you could set up AdoQuery2's SQL.Text in the IDE at design time if you wanted to.

The next two lines

```
  AdoQuery2.Parameters.ParamByName('ID').Value := 1;
  AdoQuery2.Parameters.ParamByName('Money').Value := 99;
```

specify the values which the parameters are to be set to for when the UPDATE is actually executed.  The ID value is the Row iD (aka primary key) of the row in the table which is to be updated.  Before the UPDATE staement is actually executed, the AdoQuery parses the SQL and creates the parameters if they don't alteady exist (you can create them at design time in the IDE by editing the Parameters property of the AdoQuery.

Finally

```
  AdoQuery2.ExecSQL;
```

is what actually executes the UPDATE statement.  Note that you can repeat the steps of setting the parameter values and calling ExecSQL as many times as you want.

The main thing which was wrong with your UPDATE statement was that you were using double-quote (`"`) marks, whereas when a SQL statement needs quote marks (and values of numeric columns do NOT) they should be single quotes(`'`).  A complication when constructing a SQL statement in Delphi code is that its syntax requires single quotes which are to be embedded in the SQL to be doubled up.

Note also that you should **always** used parameterised SQL for your SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE statements as this helps protect your app against [Sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Making, say, an unparameterised statement accessible to the user can allow a malicious user to attempt to execute any SQL they wish.

Answer (score -1):

In your question, you did not indicate what type of column is 'Money'.  If it's varchar, char, then I understand why you might convert NewAmount to a string.

However, if the database expects numeric value (because the field is of type int, double, dec, or float), the syntax would be `SET Money= '+ NewAmount +'`.

Comment: The OP said the Money column was an Int(eger) one, not a character one.  Also, given that some SO users are apt to thoughtlessly copy and paste code from an answer, it's not a good idea to show an UPDATE statement which is lacking a restricting WHERE clause.

Comment: You cannot concatenate a string and a float or integer directly. The example you've posted as suitable for *type int, double, dec or float* will not compile, so that syntax is incorrect. It's better if you read the tags to understand the language for which you're writing an answer, and to not answer if you're not familiar with that language.